# Most useful user scripts to improve web-apps?

Tags: greasemonkey

In Firefox it is possible to add extra functionality to web applications with extensions such as [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) and [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/). [Opera](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/) also has this feature natively. Which of these types of scripts do you find the most useful?

Comment: Google Chrome also supports many Greasemonkey scripts by automatically converting them to extensions: http://blog.chromium.org/2010/02/40000-more-extensions.html

Answer (score 3):

There's a script [published on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54078/remove-the-faq-popup/54101#54101) that hides the FAQ popup that appears when you first visit a StackExchange site.

Answer (score 0):

[Cookie Zapper](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/68231) can be useful for some sites, although it's lower-left status is annoying.